# VSCode. How do I remove padding between side bar and editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I somehow added padding to the left and right of my editor. Anyone know how I could remove it?

I've played around with view->editor layout but `Single` mode doesn't do the trick. And switching to the other views and back don't do anything either. I also can't drag the window beyond what is shown below.

my current settings.json, nothing in here should affect it.

```
{
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "editor.detectIndentation": false,
  "window.zoomLevel": 1,
  "editor.minimap.enabled": true,
  "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "[terraform]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  },
  "breadcrumbs.enabled": true,
  "[python]": {
    "editor.insertSpaces": true,
    "editor.tabSize": 4
  },
  "editor.renderWhitespace": "none"
}
```

[image: red box is the padding]

Answer (score 11):

Seems like it was answered on github. I just wasn't typing in the correct question. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/53778

F1->Toggle Center Layout

Comment: Is it possibile for you to tick your own answer for future reference? Or can you not accept your own answer?

Answer (score 4):

In settings

"editor.glyphMargin": false

Comment: maybe it's related to your current theme. did you try this on default theme?

Comment: This worked for me. It didn't remove the gutter entirely but by about 2/3s. The remaining gutter is similar to what I see on VimR and doesn't bother me so much.